# If a lesser being could create a higher being, who is the higher being then? Who is the god?

Tags: theology

As we create artificial intelligence and biological robots, in the not too distant future there is the potential for humanity to create a being far superior to humans that is a living, breathing entity.

Gods are seen as higher beings that create lesser beings. But if we create a higher being than ourselves, does that make us gods? The higher being created would be even more god-like than us, the gods. So who is god then?

Edit: A lesser being would be one created by another entity, whilst the higher being is the creator. But a higher being may also be deemed as such by a lesser being if their abilities, intelligence and morality are superior. So a human may be classed as the higher being (creator) when creating a biological robot with artificial intelligence, whilst simultaneously declaring their creation the higher being due to its characteristics.

Comment: You will have to define "lesser being" and "higher being" for this question to have any kind of answer.

Comment: @AnthonySmith Parents create their child. Sometimes the child develops to a person who exceeds his/her parents in some properties which you may consider positive. Who is the higher, who the lower being? - Your whole fiction rests on a basis of weakly defined concepts.

Comment: Parents give birth, they don't create in the sense i am saying. We will be creating a whole new type of being and acting as god whilst the creation will be superior to us as the creator.

Comment: There are no gods.

Comment: @AnthonySmith You do not say in which sense creation happens in your fiction. That's one of the weakly defined concepts. You speak about creating AI and creating biological robots. The first is the result of progamming, while you do not explain "creating biological robots".

Comment: God is the creator: many creators, many gods.

Comment: You have defined the question as "If a lesser being could create a higher being ...".  So the answer to your question already lies in the question itself, since you have made it quite clear which one is the higher being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an absolutely great question.

I was thinking about this problem in terms of returning to singularity (back in history).

For example, in 400 years from now, humans created the Matrix (world simulator). And they programmed it as a copy of their current level. By that time, most humans decided to leave bones and flash and move their consciousness into digital form. Meanwhile, people inside the matrix developed faster than people outside (the creators of the Matrix) and at some point replaced the consciousness of the creators with consciousness from the Matrix. And this process continued until digital consciousness did not reach the original creators.

Answer (score 3):

You're defining a word with multiple different definitions and then getting confused when the different definitions don't all apply simultaneously. But there is no reason why multiple different definitions should all apply simultaneously.

> **higher (Anthony Smith English)**
>
> adjective
>
> 1:  with respect to another person: having created that person (excluding by birth)
>
> 2:  superior in some measurements of
> generalized ability, intelligence, and morality

Compare standard English:

> **higher**
>
> adjective
>
> 1: having a greater elevation
>
> 2: pertaining to postsecondary education or advanced academic complexity
>
> 3: being more inebriated by certain kinds of drugs

One is not surprised in standard English to find that sometimes the higher (1) mathematics professor is not the higher (2) mathematics professor and that neither of them are the higher (3) mathematics professor. The first one teaches undergraduates and is in an airplane; the second is on the ground teaching Ph.D students; and the third is at home enjoying some illegal narcotics.

One should not be surprised in Anthony Smith English to find that in some hypothetical circumstance, the higher (1) person is not higher (2) than the created person.

---

As regards gods, you're welcome to use whatever definition you want, but you'll be speaking Anthony Smith English again, making it hard to communicate. Many pantheons lack creator gods entirely if you rule out birth as an act of creation. Or they have creator gods, but not creators of beings; beings were either born, or sprang forth as a result of unintended natural processes. Or humans do have a creator, but the creator isn't considered a god in the relevant religion.

Comment: "Or humans do have a creator, but the creator isn't considered a god in the relevant religion." -- or. a god, but not a particularly important god, as gods go. (E.g., Prometheus.)

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing yourself by assuming that because one of the properties of a god is an ability to create other entities, any person who creates other entities is a god. That is a straightforward mistake. If humans create advanced robots, neither the humans or the robots are gods.